# what is the best approach to move /var?

Tags: filesystems, rhel, rsync, cp, file-copy

we have linux red hat 7

we want to keep the /var on other volume

so the plan is to:

```
mkdir /var_copy
cp -rp /var/* /var_copy
umount /dev/mapper/vg-a-var /var
rm -rf /var
mkdir /var
mount /dev/mapper/vg-b-var /var
cp -rp /var_copy/* /var
```

so my question is

is it good approach to use **cp -rp** in order to copy **/var** content ?

or maybe because /var include symbolic link or hard link need to use other approach ?

Comment: There will be a lot of processes writing to /var and so copying the data on a "live" system will be difficult. How many disks are associated with the volume?

Comment: I'd boot off a CD/DVD and not try copying `/var` on a live system.  I'd also use a direct filesystem copy from old device to new device. I can easily imagine `cp` having problems with special types of files, or files with multiple hardlinks.  Maybe `dd` then `growfs` works for `ext[3|4]`?

Comment: Bear in mind that these are logical volumes and so pvmove may be an option here

Comment: what about cp -a  ( I think this is the best ) ?   seer also - https://askubuntu.com/questions/86822/how-can-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-folder-to-another-folder-in-a-different-directo/86844